# Filter Lookup column based on Current Logged in user

Tags: lookup-column, caml-query, filter, spservices

I have a small problem i am facing in CAML queries. 
Currently i am trying to filter a Lookup column based on Current logged in User in SharePoint Online.
Here is my code and i am new to using SP services and CAML Queries.

```
<script type="text/javascript src="/sites/CC2344/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript src="/sites/CC2344/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
var userName = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "Name" });

  var query = '<Query>' +
            '<Where>' + 
                '<Eq>' +
                    '<FieldRef Name="Employee" />' +
                        '<Value Type="User">' + userName + '</Value>' +
                '</Eq>' +
            '</Where>' +
        '</Query>'; 

 $().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "TimeTracker",
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
CAMLQuery: query,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        // will return only results that match the current logged in user
        // in the 'SharePointUser' column
        console.log($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
  });

  });            
 });
</script>
```

Please do help me out , because i am really struggling with this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


var query = '<Query>' +
        '<Where>' + 
            '<Eq>' +
                '<FieldRef Name="Employee" />' +
                    '<Value Type="User"><UserID/></Value>' +
            '</Eq>' +
        '</Where>' +
    '</Query>'; 

$().SPServices({
operation: "GetListItems",
async: false,
listName: "TimeTracker",
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
CAMLQuery: query,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
    // will return only results that match the current logged in user
    // in the 'SharePointUser' column
    console.log($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
});
});            
});
</script>
```

[Query regarding user you can refer this link](http://www.ashokraja.me/tips/How-to-use-User-Name-User-Id-Logged-in-User-Id-in-SharePoint-CAML-Query)

Comment: i cannot quite wrap my head around the query itself. could you possibly help me out on this one, so i can explain everything and see what works out ?

Comment: Its just a query for your SharePoint List "TimeTracker" where you are trying retrieve items where the filed/column "Employee" is equal to current logged in user. And adding to it the viewfields means you specify the field to return from list.

Comment: What does the FieldRef Name='Title' defines here ?

Comment: It refer to field/column's name in list "TimeTracker" and in caml query we usually specify the internal name of the column.

Comment: i am still not able to figure this out, guess i am really stuck

Comment: You need to understand/read the basic of SharePoint query before coding on it that would make easier for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77571/discussion-between-sunil-sahu-and-jayant-khushalani).

Answer (score 0):

Filtering data against current *userId* is better.
Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userId = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ fieldName: "ID" });

    var query = '<Query>' +
            '<Where>' + 
                '<Eq>' +
                    '<FieldRef Name="Employee" LookupId="TRUE"/>' +
                        '<Value Type="User">' + userId + '</Value>' +
                '</Eq>' +
            '</Where>' +
        '</Query>'; 

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "TimeTracker",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        CAMLQuery: query,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                // will return only results that match the current logged in user
                // in the 'SharePointUser' column
                console.log($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
            });
        }

    });            
 });
```

Assuming that "`Employee`" column is *Person or Group* type.

**Edit**
Since "`Employee`" is a Lookup column, change the CAML query like this,

```
var userDetails = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldNames: ["ID", "UserName", "FirstName", "LastName"],
        debug: false
    });

    var userFullName = userDetails.FirstName + " " + userDetails.LastName;
    var query = '<Query>' +
            '<Where>' + 
                '<Eq>' +
                    '<FieldRef Name="Employee"/>' +
                        '<Value Type="Lookup">' + userFullName + '</Value>' +
                '</Eq>' +
            '</Where>' +
        '</Query>';
```

Assuming "`Employee`" column contains the *FullName*, if it contains *UserName* take current `username` & use it in the CAML query

Comment: Employee Column is a text field which is a look column.

Comment: you mean *Employee* column is a Lookup column  type?

Comment: yes, employee is a lookup column type!

Comment: Updated the answer, check it

Comment: i updated the query , but unfortunately it is still not working. Does the code after this query needs to be changed too?

Comment: No need to change the entire code, change the current user details retrieval & query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77568/discussion-between-vishnu-s-and-jayant-khushalani).

Comment: so the lookup employee still contains all the employees name. So i am not able to see this working !